# Swift: get a menu item by its selector

Tags: swift, cocoa

Instead of doing this:

```
let myItem = NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu?.itemAtIndex(3)?.submenu?.itemAtIndex(5)
```

Is there a way to get myItem by its selector? Looking like this maybe:

```
let myItem = NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu?.itemOrSubItemBySelector(#selector(doSomething))
```

This is not a real world question, it is more out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in for loop if any item is responding to that selector but in overall it looks really bad, even for not real life question, we should use something smarter

```
item.respondsToSelector(#selector(doSomething))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
let item = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
           .mainMenu!.itemArray.filter(){ $0.submenu!.title == "View" }[0]
           .submenu!.itemArray.filter(){ $0.action == #selector(MyView.toggleVisibility) }[0]
```

EDIT:

In the end I decided to go with an extension on NSMenu using a nested recursion function:

```
extension NSMenu {

  func itemBySelector(selector: Selector) -> NSMenuItem? {

    func recurse(menu: NSMenu) -> NSMenuItem? {
      for item in menu.itemArray {
        if item.action == selector {
          return item
        } else if let submenu = item.submenu {
          if let item = recurse(submenu) {
            return item
          }
        }
      }
      return nil
    }
    return recurse(self)

  }

}
```